# Toggle specific div based on click, hide all other divs of the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, slidetoggle, dom-manipulation

See my current code here: http://jsfiddle.net/swQLg/3/

I have some div's like

```
<div class="qtn">question1</div>
<div class="ans">answer1</div>
<div class="qtn">question2</div>
<div class="ans">answer2</div>
<div class="qtn">question3</div>
<div class="ans">answer3</div>
<div class="qtn">question4</div>
<div class="ans">answer4</div>
```

my jquery function is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".qtn").on('click', function () {
        $(this).next(".ans").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

When I show one answer, I would like it to hide the other answers if they are showing.

Comment: Did you mean that you wanted to hide all div's on click, apart from the one you're opening?

Comment: you want to have only one answer div opened at a time.right?

Comment: Nevermind, two spot-on answers have already done it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".qtn").on('click', function () {
        var $ans = $(this).next(".ans");
        $ans.slideToggle(); //toggle the current one
        $(".ans").not($ans).slideUp(); //hide the others
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/swQLg/10/)

The reason I save `$(this).next(".ans");` to a variable is for performance. If I didn't do this, every time that you call `$(this).next(".ans");`, jQuery would have to wrap `this` into a jquery object and then perform the `next()` function on that jquery object. In this case that would only be 1 extra time, but that still means 2 unnecessary operations.

Here is a [**jsperf test**](http://jsperf.com/cache-vs-no-cache434) demonstrating the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Put `slideUp()` in your click event to slide everything up. This will take care of closing/hiding already open divs and then put your code.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/swQLg/9/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".qtn").on('click', function () {
        $(".ans").not($(this).next(".ans")).slideUp(); // slide the rest up
        $(this).next(".ans").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Edited to fix what  @smerny pointed out.

Comment: This will hide, and then show the current element when the user tries to hide it.